# Run docker commands using glob / wildcard on container names

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose up --scale` to create multiple versions of the same container. As a result I end up with containers named `container_foo_1`, `container_foo_2` etc.

Does docker support any kind of glob / wildcard matching on container names in it's command line tools? What I want to do is this:

`docker inspect container_foo_*`

What I'm doing right now in the short term is just using:

`docker-inspect container_foo_{1,2}` (using bash brace expansion)

but I'd love if there was a way where I didn't know how many containers there were / what the numbers were ahead of time.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the argument `--filter | -f` at `docker ps` with `docker inspect`.

**Usage:** `docker ps --filter key=value`,
where `value` accept regular expressions.

The currently supported filters are:

- `id`  Container’s ID
- `name`    Container’s name
- `label`   An arbitrary string representing either a key or a key-value pair. Expressed as  or =
- `exited`  An integer representing the container’s exit code. Only useful with --all.
- `status`  One of created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited, or dead
- `ancestor`    Filters containers which share a given image as an ancestor. Expressed as * [:], , or image@digest
- `before or since` Filters containers created before or after a given container ID or name
- `volume`  Filters running containers which have mounted a given volume or bind mount.
- `network` Filters running containers connected to a given network.
- `publish or expose`   Filters containers which publish or expose a given port. Expressed as `<port>[/<proto>]` or `<startport-endport>/[<proto>]`
- `health`  Filters containers based on their healthcheck status. One of starting, healthy, unhealthy or none.
- `isolation`   Windows daemon only. One of default, process, or hyperv.
- `is-task` Filters containers that are a “task” for a service. Boolean option (true or false)

**Ex:** `docker inspect $(docker ps --filter name=^/server --quiet)`

References:

- [Filtering](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)
- [How to filter docker ps by *exact* name?](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-filter-docker-ps-by-exact-name/2880/3)